# CALayer rasterize performance degredation

Tags: objective-c

I have a CALayer which I drag across the screen.  I want a shadow on the layer, so I create one and rasterize it into a bitmap.  I was hoping that the rasterized version with shadow would have the same performance when dragged as the image without the shadow, but it's worse.  If the image is rasterized, why is it worse?  Is there a better way to add a shadow without degrading performance noticeably?  I create the shadow and contents as follows:

```
layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"imageURI"]].CGImage;
layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
layer.shadowOpacity = .5;
layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a CALayer shadow, you should use the `shadowPath` property. You would use it like so:

```
layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
```